# Sharepoint 2013 get absolute URL of List using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, javascript, jsom, url

I have the below code to the the relative server URL. How do i get the absolute url so I can add it to an onclick object? Is there a get_serverRelativeUrl() equivalent function for absolute URL?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var list;
var listRootFolder;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, "sp.js");

function init() {

    //load site
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext('/StrategicProjectOffice');
    list = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test List');
    listRootFolder = list.get_rootFolder();

    currentcontext.load(list, 'Title', 'Id');
    currentcontext.load(listRootFolder);
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, result), Function.createDelegate(this, oncListQueryFailed));
}

function result() {
    var listID   = list.get_id();
    var listName = list.get_title();
    var listURL  = listRootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl();
    console.log(listURL);
}

function oncListQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Document library:**

Just append the **`_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`** as shown below code to get absolute url of the list.

```
function result() {
    var listID   = list.get_id();
    var listName = list.get_title();
    var listURL  = listRootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl();
    var absUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl +"/"+ listURL; //absUrl is now absolute url of the list.
}
```

---

**For List:**

Just append the **`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`** as shown below code to get absolute url of the list. Just update methods as shown below.

```
function init() {

    //load site
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext('/StrategicProjectOffice');
    list = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test List');
    listRootFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
    web = currentcontext.get_web();

    currentcontext.load(list, 'Title', 'Id');
    currentcontext.load(web);
    currentcontext.load(listRootFolder);
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, result), Function.createDelegate(this, oncListQueryFailed));
}

function result() {
    var listID   = list.get_id();
    var listName = list.get_title();
    var listURL  = listRootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl();
    var absUrl = web.get_url() + "/Lists/" + listRootFolder.get_name(); //absUrl is now absolute url of the list.
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the list is in the same site that the script is running on.  Wouldn't work if it was on a different site.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `_spPageContextInfo` to create a full url. I couldnt find a specific method, so i modified your code as below. This is will work for Lists only, for document library  you need to remove `/Lists/` from the code. Not necessarily the best approach, but works as expected.

```
var list;
var listRootFolder;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, "sp.js");

function init() {

    //load site
    var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext('/StrategicProjectOffice');
    list = currentcontext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test List');
    listRootFolder = list.get_rootFolder();

    currentcontext.load(list, 'Title', 'Id');
    currentcontext.load(listRootFolder);
    currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, result), Function.createDelegate(this, oncListQueryFailed));
}

function result() {
    var listID   = list.get_id();
    var listName = list.get_title();
    var listURL  = listRootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl();
    console.log(listURL);

    var fullUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/" + listRootFolder.get_name();
    console.log(fullUrl);
}

function oncListQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```